# Cause an array of events Backbone event:name

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
_.extend(object, Backbone.Events);

object.on("myalert:one", function(msg) {
  document.body.innerHTML+=("eve1 " + ' msg:= '+msg+ ' ;name:= '+this.name);
},context);


object.on("myalert:two", function(msg) {
  document.body.innerHTML+=(" eve2 " + ' msg:= '+msg+ ' ;name:= '+this.name);
});
```

I want сall all events are tied to this object with mask **alert:.**

```
   object.trigger("myalert", "param");
```

Comment: I don't think you can namespace events this way. you can do it with model attributes because backbone binds individual events to each attribute as well the general event. http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any namespacing in `Backbone.Events` but you could add your own. For example, something like this:

```
obj.trigger_matching = function(re) {
    var args = [''].concat([].splice.call(arguments, 1));
    for(name in this._events) {
        if(!name.match(re))
            continue;
        args[0] = name;
        this.trigger.apply(this, args);
    }
};
```

would allow you to say `obj.trigger_matching(/^myalert:/, 1, 2, 3)` and The Right Thing would happen.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/p8p5R/

That will trigger multiple `'all'` events (one for each `this.trigger.apply`) which may or may not be what you want. If it isn't then replace the `this.trigger.apply` call with a custom version of the standard [`trigger`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L136) so that you can trigger at most one `'all'` event.

Comment: put this on the list as something that backbone should take care of out of the box