# How to trigger Backbone event with "qualifier"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to trigger a render event when my views are being rendered.

```
function Renderer() {
    _.extend(this, Backbone.Events);
};

Renderer.prototype.render = function(view, model) {
    this.trigger('render:before');

    // Do some checks to see how
    // we should render the view
    // and then call render

    this.trigger('render:after');
};

var renderer = new Renderer();
```

Now I can register for events on the `Renderer`, but I must use the full name. I.e. this works:

```
renderer.on('render:before', function() { console.log("before rendering"); });
renderer.on('render:after', function() { console.log("after rendering"); });
renderer.on('all', function() { console.log("All events from renderer"); });
```

But this does not:

```
renderer.on('render', function() { console.log("Any rendering events"); });
```

I expected the last one to be equivalent to registering on `all` events for the renderer.

**Is there a way to make listening to `render` equivalent to listening for both `render:before` and `render:after`?**

Comment: Is this the same thing as http://stackoverflow.com/q/20163043/479863 ?

Comment: @muistooshort It's sort of the inverse of that. I wan't to receive all events when registering on 'render'. That question seems to be about triggering all listeners registered with "qualifiers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespacing event names by using the colon is [just a convention](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on):

> If you have a large number of different events on a page, the
>   convention is to use colons to namespace them: "poll:start", or
>   "change:selection".

The [source code of `Events.trigger`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-22) shows that the event handler to be called is searched for by the full name of the event, independently of whether it contains a colon or not:

```
var events = this._events[name];
...
if (events) triggerEvents(events, args);
```

You can:

- define and trigger an `'all'` event,
- trigger multiple event handlers by calling `trigger` with a space-delimited list of event names, or
- modify the source code of `Events.trigger` in backbone.js to add this feature.