# Backbone nested / namespaced events

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

```
var o = {}
_.extend(o, Backbone.Events)

o.on('custom', function(){ console.log("A nested event was triggered!"); })

o.trigger('custom:nested', otherDataThatINeed);
```

Is there a build in functionality like showed for nested events in backbone? Has anyone implemented such a functionality before? (Google search returns absolutely nothing)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cause an array of events Backbone event:name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163043/cause-an-array-of-events-backbone-eventname)

Answer (score 0):

Event names are simply labels, there is no hierarchy to them.

You may want to add options to your event and add some logic to handle them when the event is called.

```
o.trigger('custom', {'secondevent': 'nestedeventname', 'somedata': otherDataThatINeed});
```